# MySQL how to get a result with one to many relationship with Where clause

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have two tables Person with attributes (id, name), a person can have multiple Books with attributes (Name, Status) status if he has completed the book or not. How can I get the results for when a person has completed book A but not completed book B.

```
Select * 
from Person, Book, PersonBook 
Where Person.id = PersonBook.personid 
  and Book.id = PersonBook.bookid 
  and (    book.name = "BookA" 
       and book.status like "%Completed%") 
  and (    book.name = "BookB" 
       and book.status not like "%Completed%")
```

What changes should I make to this query to get the desired result because currently this query will return empty result.

Comment: *status if he has completed the book or not* Show real values for 'completed' and 'not completed' values. For example, `'Not Completed'` value matches `like "%Completed%"` condition...

Comment: In order to understand more, can you please give us a sample of data from three of those tables? And please post in texts not images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
select pb.* from PersonBook pb join Person p on pb.personid = p.id join Book b1 on pb.bookid = b1.id and b1.name = "BookA" and b1.status like "Completed" join Book b2 on pb.bookid = b2.id and b2.name = "BookB" and b2.status not like "Completed"
```

Have not tried it but it should work just fine, also make sure no syntax error are there as I have not checked it.

Let me know if it does not work.

Good luck !